# No Bluetooth on Dell Vostro 3500

Tags: bluetooth, dell-vostro

I recently purchased a Dell Vostro 3500. I could not find any way of activating the bluetooth device. I looked at the BIOS and tried installing the bluetooth drivers which said that no bluetooth device was found. So I went onto the Dell website to confirm that the laptop should come with Bluetooth which it should. The laptop even came with the Bluetooth status light symbol above the keyboard. I was wondering if there is any way to confirm that there is infact no bluetooth device on my laptop or that the device is there but not working?

Answer (score 3):

Run lsusb on unix-like systems or go to control panel-> system -> device manager and look for bluetooth there on windows. If it isn't there, you probably don't have it.

Keep in mind that in same series there could be laptops with Bluetooth and without Bluetooth. Both will have same external indicators because it's cheaper to include Bluetooth light on all laptops then it is to make two versions: One for Bluetooh laptops and other for laptops without Bluetooth.

Also read your computer's specifications. They are probably printed somewhere on its box. Keep in mind that is is possible that you payed for laptop with Bluetooth and got one without.

In the end only sure way to confirm if there is a malfunctioning Bluetooth radio is to open the laptop and look for it. Unfortunately, it would be quite complicated to disassemble the laptop and it could void your warranty.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Windows are you running? If Windows 7, run windows update it usually finds the latest drivers for your hardware devices. Can you see Bluetooth devices in device manager if not, do you have any devices not recognized in device manager ? Check for the same and please reply back here.

This is how it shows up in device manager on my Dell Inspiron 1525, obviously with drivers correctly installed.
*(I'm running Windows 7 and my older Bluetooth drivers just got updated today)*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is actually Bluetooth.

If there is one, re-seating it in the compartment may fix the connection issue, or it could be a bad piece of hardware potentially. There are also settings in the BIOS that control how the "wireless" switch behaves - does it turn off all radios (Bluetooth, Wifi, cellular, etc.) - or just some. I generally just disable that switch all together in the BIOS as it tends to cause nothing but trouble.

For good measure, you may want to try and update your BIOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop doesn't have bluetooth. Believe me: I have the same one!

Comment: I have the same machine and it says it has bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

The Dell Vostro 3500 does have bluetooth! Even if it doesnt show in your device manager. Go to the downloads section on the Dell website and download the Bluetooth driver and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Dell Vestro 3500 does come with a bluetooth and preinstalled driver! Just go to the system tray and show the hidden icons. I bet you will find the bluetooth incon and know how to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the model **has** Bluetooth.

first you have to install all other drivers then ,
Download the driver `DELL_WIRELESS-365-BLUETOOTH-_A00_R253452` from the Dell website for the Vostro 3500, but before install, first turn on the wireless by using the switch in front of the laptop (in this model, to use Bluetooth you have to turn on the wireless), then install the driver and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It says that no Bluetooth device is detected during the installation of the driver.

Comment: dont forget to turn on the wireless by using the switch in front of the laptop .

Comment: Do I also have to be connected to a wifi network?

Comment: no , just turn on the wireless by using the switch in front of the laptop before install.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the Service Tag number on the [Dell Support Website](http://support.dell.com/).  If it was originally equipped with a BT Transceiver from Dell, it should show up on the order sheet.